# patched not applied after magento upgrade

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have upgraded Magento from `1.9.2.1 to 1.9.4.1` and it was successful.but
when i check site security in https://www.magereport.com then
it show all patches applied except

> Security patch 8788
>
> what could be possible reason for that and how can i fix it.

also when i tried to install it from ssh it show me below error.

```
> checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php Reversed (or previously
> applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] Apply anyway? [n] Skipping
> patch. 1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instruction here

```
https://magecomp.com/blog/install-magento-supee-8788-with-or-without-ssh/
```

You can do it in both way with SSH and without SSH, try to download the patch files and replace them using FTP.